# Buscar usuario-login con MySql y Java

Tags: java, mysql

tengo un problema, y es que el if(rs.next()) si bien encuentra el usuario y guarda sus datos en las correspondientes variables, solo lo hace con el primero que encuentra. La idea es que al loguearse con cualquier usuario permita acceder mientras los datos sean correctos.

```
private void button_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    usuario = txt_usuario.getText();
    contraseña = txt_pass.getText();

    try {

        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/servicio_tecnico", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT username,password,tipo_nivel,nombre_usuario FROM usuarios");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            usuarioCorrecto = rs.getString(1);
            contraseñaCorrecta = rs.getString(2);
            tipo_nivel = rs.getString(3);
            nombre = rs.getString(4);
        }

        if (usuario.equals(usuarioCorrecto) && contraseña.equals(contraseñaCorrecta)) {
            if (tipo_nivel.equals("Administrador")) {
                ventanaMenu vm = new ventanaMenu();
                this.setVisible(false);
                vm.setVisible(true);
            } else if (tipo_nivel.equals("Capturista")) {

            } else if (tipo_nivel.equals("Tecnico")) {

            }

        } else if (!usuario.equals(usuarioCorrecto) || !contraseña.equals(contraseñaCorrecta)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
    }

}
```

Funciona nada mas con el primer elemento de la tabla. A los demas se salta al else de que es incorrecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si estoy entendiendo bien. ¿Estas tratando de hacer un sistema de ingreso?.

En el código que pasas va a obtener todos los usuarios de la base de datos.
Luego va a obtener el primer registro.
Luego analiza si el usuario tiene los datos correctos o no, y termina.

Si queres que haga este proceso hasta revisar todos los usuarios o encontrar el correcto (lo primero que se de) tenes que poner un ciclo. Y solo devolver el error cuando el ciclo finalizo porque reviso todos los usuarios y no encontro el correcto.

Igualmente pensa que si tenes 10.000 usuarios, cada vez que quieras validar un usuario y clave se van a tener que recorrer esos 10.000 usuarios (en el peor de los casos).

Lo que te recomiendo es que traigas desde la base de datos solamente el usuario que te interesa.

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT username,password,tipo_nivel,nombre_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE username=?");
pst.setString(1, usuario )
```

Luego, si no existe el registro, el usuario es invalido.
Si el registro existe, chequeas la contraseña.

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que planteas tiene algunos errores que pueden pasar factura según crezca tu modelo de datos.

El mas grande es realizar una consulta de toda la tabla para obtener el listado de usuarios. Lo primero seria que la SQL solo diera con el resultado del usuario por username o ninguno. Para ello se ha de añadir un filtro.  Si este filtro estarias recorriendo toda la tabla si el ususario no es válido lo que es una perdida de tiempo y memoria. Ademas de poder ocasionar errores OutOfMemoryException si no tenemos memoria suficiente para obtener toda la tabla en memoria.

El segundo problema es poner las variables "usuario" y "contraseña" como variables de la clase. Si esta clase es un "singleton" podrias tener problemas de concurrencia y un usuario acceda como otro (entre otras cosas). O que se use el nombre guardado anteriormente al realizar login de nuevo.

Ejemplo usando el select con filtro:

```
String usuario  = txt_usuario.getText();
String password = txt_pass.getText();

Connection cn;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
try {

    // Se inicializa a null
    String usuarioCorrecto = null;
    String passwordCorrecta = null;
    String tipo_nivel = null;
    String nombre = null;


    // Realizar la conexion SQL 
    cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/servicio_tecnico", "root", "");

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT username,password,tipo_nivel,nombre_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?");
    pst.setString(1, usuario )
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    // Solo se obtiene el primer registro (Si existe)
    if (rs.next()) {
        usuarioCorrecto = rs.getString(1);
        passwordCorrecta = rs.getString(2);
        tipo_nivel = rs.getString(3);
        nombre = rs.getString(4);
    }

    // Si se ha obtenido un usuario y password y ademas esta es coincidente
    if (usuarioCorrecto !=null && password!=null && password.equals(passwordCorrecta)) {
        if(tipo_nivel!=null){
            if (tipo_nivel.equals("Administrador")) {
                ventanaMenu vm = new ventanaMenu();
                this.setVisible(false);
                vm.setVisible(true);
            } else if (tipo_nivel.equals("Capturista")) {

            } else if (tipo_nivel.equals("Tecnico")) {

            }
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
} finally {
    // Cierre de recursos (si se usa java7 se puede usar un try-with-resources
    if(rs!=null){
        rs.close();
    }
    if(pst!=null){
        pst.close();
    }
    if(cn!=null){
        cn.close();
    }   
}
```

Tambien seria recomendable no usar la clave en plano en la base de datos ya que cualquiera que pueda acceder a ella podra ver la clave del usuario. Seria recomendable cifrar la clave con algún cifrado de Mysql (podriamos resolverlo con una SQL mas completa) o bien algun método ajeno como usar una funcion [SHA256](https://www.baeldung.com/sha-256-hashing-java) o [MD5](https://www.baeldung.com/java-md5) en Java

Por ultimo una gestión de la conexión y el acceso a datos mediante una clase especializada puede mejorar aun mas el funcionamiento y mantenimiento futuros. Programar toda la logica en un botón, incluido abrir el acceso a datos es un mal diseño de software que puede acarrear problemas en un futuro.

En tu ejemplo tienes la logica en el metodo:

button_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

que es un metodo de una acción de un botón donde se realiza todo el proceso.

Lo ideal es que este proceso solo realizara una llamada a un metodo de login de una clase y que esta contenga toda la logica.

Ejemplo:

```
private void button_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    String usuario = txt_usuario.getText();
    String clave = txt_pass.getText(); 

    Usuario usuario = controlador.login(usuario,clave);
    if(usuario == null){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos")
    }
}
```

Donde "Usuario" seria un objeto java (un POJO) con la información del usuario y "controlador" seria un objeto con el codigo de acceso a datos y métodos como "login" para realizar el acceso

**Nota:** El codigo esta realizado sin conocer la versión de Java por lo que según la versión algunas cosas podrian ser mejor implementadas

Comment: A qué te refieres cuando hablas programar toda la lógica en un botón?